# Python Asyncio with difflib slows to a crawl

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, python-asyncio, difflib

I have a script which asynchronously downloads several urls, and then continuously monitors them for changes via difflib

```
import asyncio
import difflib
import aiohttp

urls = ['http://www.nytimes.com/',
        'http://www.time.com/',
        'http://www.economist.com/']

async def get_url(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            old = await resp.text()
            print('Initial -',url)
        while True:
            async with session.get(url) as resp1:
                new = await resp.text()
            print('Got -',url)
            diff = difflib.unified_diff(old, new)

            for line in diff:
                print(line)
            old = new

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    ops = []
    for url in urls:
        ops.append(get_url(url))
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(ops))
```

When I run it with the following lines commented

```
        for line in diff:
            print(line)
```

The script runs as expected, retrieving each url around 3 times per second.

When the lines are uncommented, the script slows down, much slower than if the retrievals were run serially.

I have no idea why this is happening, does it have something to do with difflib returning a generator?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have an error in your code, instead of `new = await resp.text()` it should be `new = await resp1.text()`.

unified_diff works with a list of strings and not directly with strings.  You can use `splitlines()` to quickly split a string into lines:

```
diff = difflib.unified_diff(old.splitlines(), new.splitlines())
```

(Currently each character in the long string is treated as a line!)